# С прописной или строчной слова "госпиталь", "больница" в официальных названиях

Tags: прописная-строчная

Подскажите, будьте добры, стоит ли писать с прописной слова "госпиталь", "больница" в названиях вроде Госпиталь Батлера, Больница Святой Марии, Диспансер Иностранного легиона (официальные названия)

Answer (score 0):

Написание с прописной возможно *только* при отличии начальных слов от формального видового наименования организации:

> *ООО* Госпиталь Батлера, *ФГУП* Больница Святой Марии, *медицинский колледж*
> Диспансер иностранного легиона...